# Split a string based on "|" delimiter & set values to different Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net

So I have the following code that I am using as a config file in my VB.Net project:

```
[User 1]
1|Test Button|C:\temp\test.csv|This Button is a test button
2|Test Button 2|C:\temp\test.csv|This Button is another test button

[User 2]
... etc
```

What I am wanting to do is have the first part go to an array called butNum(), second part go to an array called butVal(), third to go to butLink and 4th to go to butDes(). The code I have so far is as follows:

```
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If line.StartsWith("[") Then
            Dim Firstpart As String = Nothing
            Firstpart = line.Replace("[", "")
            Firstpart = Firstpart.Replace("]", "")
            If Firstpart = login.Login1.Text Then 'this checks the user has logged in as "User 1"
                While reader.ReadLine() <> ""
                    ReDim Preserve butNum(0 To lines)
                    ReDim Preserve butVal(0 To lines)
                    ReDim Preserve butLink(0 To lines)
                    ReDim Preserve butDes(0 To lines)
                    butNum(lines) = 'part 1 delimited
                    butVal(lines) = 'part 2 delimited
                    butLink(lines) = 'part 3 delimited
                    butDes(lines) = 'part 4 delimited
                    line = reader.ReadLine()
                    lines = lines + 1
                End While
            End If
            Application.DoEvents()
        Else
            Application.DoEvents()
        End If
    End While
```

As a slight aside, would my config file string values need to be in ""'s (ie `1|"Test Button"|"C:\temp\test.csv"...`)? I would assume not, but its niggling me :P

Comment: Is there a chance to switch to a better format?
Like a normal datatable which contains just columns like this: USER, BUTTON_NR, BUTTON_NAME, PATH, TEXT.
The main benefit would be that you could very easily store this information as a csv file (look up the library http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/) and easily transfer the data into your arrays.
That is way easier than defining your own data storage format and spares you tons of little bugs.

Comment: The reason for this is so that we can easily edit them "on the fly" in notepad once the details are set. Plus, I dont want to use "," as the delimiter, purely for the fact that it may sometimes be used in the descriptions.

Comment: @ChristianSauer Will agree that adding User to the first part and having a 5 part array may make it easier to code. Was going for a more user-friendly looking text file though (as ideally I want people to be able to edit it fairly easily) so if it were possible the way it is currently, it would be a better solution in that sense.

Comment: While it might look like more user-friendly it is not. Your format is easy to butch, maybe missing a delimiter, or misstyping User or simply adding too much blank lines.
A csv is easy to edit in Excel or any other office tool and it's structure is more familiar to most users.

Comment: As a additional comment: Are you aware of List<string> ? They are much more powerful and useful than arrays. I think in most circumstances it is better to use a List.

Comment: @ChristianSauer Cant say I am aware of that, no. Still a fair old Newbie in VB.Net. Took me a while just to get my head round arrays when I first used them in VBA :P. And in terms of User Freindliness, it's not ideal but it works and is similar in format to something else we edit anyway, so its not such a leap in terms of our standpoint. Plus, this may also at times be used on a new PC that we have not installed Excel on yet, so it will still be read in Notepad whatever we do.

Comment: Oh, then you should read some articles about lists. They are more flexible than arrays (adding / deleting items without redim etc.).
Also, they have a ton of methods, like sorting searching etc. which makes them easy to use.
I found the leap from array to list very easy and time saving.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-vbnet

Comment: Ah ok. Quite similar to a dropdown box list control, but without the box. Quite useful to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using split string function for your second line.

Also as Christian mentioned if you could change the format so that all information is in one line User1|1|Test Button|...... would be better as you could use the split function and get all details in one go.

Example of using split

```
Dim secondlinestring As String = "1|Test Button|C:\temp\test.csv|This Button is a test button"
Dim strarr() As String
strarr = secondlinestring.Split("|"c)
For Each s As String In strarr
    MessageBox.Show(s)
Next
```

strarr is your array of each split of the secondlinestring so strarr(0) = "1" strarr(1) = "Test Button" etc.

As you can see having all details in one line separated by | would save you having to write code to allow for first and second line differences.

Comment: As I have written above, I would like to keep the format as it is if possible, purely for ease of access. How would I use the split function further on in my code and have it pass the correct variables to each array? Would it be a case of splitting them to a `temp(0 to 3)` array then setting each to its correct array? As with me not being great with `Split` yet (and still a VB.Net novice :P) then I was thinking this way would be an option, but there may be other faster ways too.

Comment: You Dim an array and the assign it a string which contains your second line and split on the | character. I've added example code in my answer above

Comment: Useful. One thing I have never understood when I have seen `Split`. What is with the `c` after the delimiter string?

Comment: Split is very useful. You can include several character to split on in one command. The c denote that the split is by character. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx which gives examples.