# Split Database column string into multiple variables

Tags: vb.net, string, split, oracle10g

I have a string value within my database that shows something like this (**within one column**) :

```
100 | | | 6 |  |  | 8 |
```

where the blanks between the `|` are empty strings depending on what the user initially provided.

I have 7 textboxes that get filled for each value between the `|`. 
I want to split the values and fill them in each textbox like so

```
Textbox1 = 100
Textbox2 = ""
Textbox3 = ""
Textbox4 = 6

...etc
```

What I plan to do is if the textboxes are empty I will hide them (I know how to do this). I just need help splitng the strings.

I tried referencing [Split a string based on "|" delimiter & set values to different Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547826/split-a-string-based-on-delimiter-set-values-to-different-arrays) by doing the following for my code :

```
If Not DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(16) Is DBNull.Value Then

   LargeBus.Text = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(16)
End If

Dim webV As String = LargeBus.Text
Dim secondlinestring As String = webV
Dim strarr() As String
strarr = secondlinestring.Split("|"c)
  For Each s As String In strarr
            MsgBox(s)
  Next
```

I added the full string of the column `If DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(16)` into the first of the 7 textboxes so that I could then save it as a string and split. Issue is when the MsgBox pops up the box is empty. So my splitting isn't working plus **what I really want is to split each number inside the `|` and save them to a new variable like so**:

```
var1 = 100
var2 = ""
var3 = ""
var4 = 6   ...etc
```

**Any help is appreciated.**

I also tried [splitting a string into multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199606/splitting-a-string-into-multiple-variables) with:

```
Dim str As String = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(16)
        Dim strarr As String = str.Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        Dim str1 As String = strarr(0)
        Dim str2 As String = strarr(1)
        Dim str3 As String = strarr(2)
        Dim str4 As String = strarr(3)
        Dim str5 As String = strarr(4)
        Dim str6 As String = strarr(5)
        Dim str7 As String = strarr(6)
```

but got error: value of type 1-dimensional array of string cannot be converted to string

Comment: if the data is actually many values glued together, consider saving them as individual values (and numbers not strings) so none of this is needed.  DBs excell at one to many relationships.  `var2 = ""` if you split on space and remove empties - you wont know where they were

Comment: I am actually splitting by `|` so the above coding should read `Dim strarr() As String = str.Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: and saving them as many values is what I want (as different variables) because the database table has to be formatted with multiple values delimited by a `|` @Plutonix

Comment: having the data represented in a delimited string for whatever, doesnt rule out the *numbers* also being stored individually for the *code* so that none of this is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @OneFineDay 's example, I figured out a way to do it.

```
Dim str As String = Convert.ToString(DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(19))
Dim strarray() As String = str.Split("|"c)


Dim x As Integer = 0

        For Each str In strarray
            Dim s As String = ""
            s = strarray(x)
            x = x + 1
        Next

        LargeBus.Text = strarray(0)
        SmallBus.Text = strarray(1)
        MinBus.Text = strarray(2)
        ...etc
```

Another issue I realized was my initial string was pulling from wrong Item() value. I had Item(16) instead of Item(19) which gave me an empty value because that column was in fact empty

Comment: By using the for each, I get all values between every delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax thing. Your missing the `()` on the variable declaration. You also may want to leave the empty entries looking at your example above. You don't need variables for each element just assign the element to the textbox.

```
 Dim strarr() As String = str.Split("|"c)

 'no variables needed
 Textbox1.Text = strarr(0)
 Textbox2.Text = strarr(1)
```

Comment: With your edit, when I change it to: `Dim strarr() As String = str.Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and do the following **`Dim str1 As String = strarr(0)`** I get an error that **`Index was outside the bounds of the array.`**

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean I don't need variables. I have 7 textboxes that need one of each value between the `|`

Comment: That error means that `strarr` has no elements. Updated answer.

Comment: I was using your code, If the `|` is the delimiter use the in the split method. You had a " " when I copied your code.

Comment: Suggest you use .Trim() `Textbox1.Text = strarr(0).trim`

Comment: @rheitzman, if the `strarr` array has no elements which is the error they are getting `.Trim` will not help.

Comment: @narue1992, the `str` variable must have a valid string with the `|` as delimiters or you will get no elements and thus your error. Debug you work and check that variable.

Comment: I tested out your coding again and it worked when I listed the full string in a variable. Issue is... your line `Textbox1.Text = strarr(0)` gives me the last one after the last `|` delimiter. I don't think this is suppose to happen? Negates all values prior

Comment: Ditto @narue1992 - also add QA logic if your data quality is not 100%. Common QA check is to check `strarr.Length` for a correct value.

Comment: Which in my case, strarray length is 8. I guess my values after splitting will always be empty. Sad face.